# Clone object in Forge Viewer

Tags: javascript, three.js, autodesk-forge, revit-api, forge

I'm trying to clone an object in Forge Viewer.
I have tried using THREE.js and creating a clone but it has different structure to the base object.

```
sceneBuilder = viewer.loadExtension("Autodesk.Viewing.SceneBuilder");
let modelBuilder = await sceneBuilder.addNewModel({
    conserveMemory: false,
    modelNameOverride: `Custom model`,
  });

let renderProxy = viewer.impl.getRenderProxy(viewer.model, fragId);
let geom = new THREE.Geometry();
let VE = Autodesk.Viewing.Private.VertexEnumerator;
VE.enumMeshVertices(renderProxy.geometry, (v: any, i: any) => {
    geom.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(v.x, v.y, v.z));
  });

  VE.enumMeshIndices(renderProxy.geometry, (a, b, c) => {
    geom.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(a, b, c));
  });
geom.computeFaceNormals();
let mesh = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.BufferGeometry().fromGeometry(geom),
    renderProxy.material
  );
(mesh as any).dbId = dbId;
modelBuilder.addMesh(mesh);
```

I found that renderProxy is also `THREE.Mesh`, but when I tried `let clone = renderProxy.clone(); modelBuilder.addMesh(clone)`, it doesn't work. Anyway to clone an object in Viewer?

Another thing, when I add a mesh by modelBuilder, I see that the created Object has added to Browser tree, but I still can't use Viewer functions with it (such as `Viewer.select(dbId); Viewer.fitToView();`)

Answer (score 0):

Cloning the `renderProxy` directly probably won't work as Forge Viewer basically returns the same `THREE.Mesh` instance whenever you request the proxy, just with different internals (for performance reasons).

The code snippet you provided (extracting vertices and faces from the proxy) is a safer choice. Is that snippet working as expected, or is it also causing issues?

Comment: The code snippet above is fine, but still some problems like handling the position, and rotation of the clone object.

Comment: Currently, I use this to get clone Mesh `viewer.impl.selectionMeshes` , it's all the same as origin mesh, but it's needed `viewer.select` to get the element. Still looking for a method that can get Mesh by dbId